# flutter: Null check operator used on a null value. Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I recently migrated my App to support null safety. I used the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to manage my App states. Even though I check for nullability, I still face an error in my code. here is the error stack:

> flutter: Null check operator used on a null value
> [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError
> (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
> #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
> #1      Tutorials.setTutorials tutorials.dart:48
> #2      _TutorialPageState.build. tutorial_page.dart:54
> #3      Consumer.buildWithChild consumer.dart:179
> #4      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build nested.dart:259
> #5      StatelessElement.build framework.dart:5156
> #6      SingleChildStatelessElement.build nested.dart:279
> #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild framework.dart:5086
> #8      Element.rebuild framework.dart:4805
> #9      ComponentElement._firstBuild framework.dart:5068

Here is my code:

tutorials.dart

```
  List<Tutorial>? _items = [];
  List<Tutorial>? get items {
    return [...?_items];
  }

  List<Tutorial>? get tutsOfASection {
    return [...?_tutsOfASection];
  }

  Tutorial? findById(int id) {
    return _tutsOfASection?.firstWhere((tut) => tut.id == id);
  }   

  setTutorials(int sectionId) async {
    final List<Tutorial>? loadedTuts = [];
    var i = 0;
    debugPrint("items: ${_items?[i].pid}");
    if (_items?[i] == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      do {
        if (_items![i].pid == sectionId) {
          loadedTuts?.add(_items![i]);
        }
        i++;
      } while (_items!.length > i);
      _tutsOfASection = loadedTuts;
    }
  }
```

tutorial_page.dart

```
  body: Consumer<Tutorials>(builder: (context, value, child) {
    if (_section?["sectionId"] != null) {
      value.setTutorials(_section!["sectionId"]);
      return TutorialScreen();
    } else
      return Container();
  }),
```

Comment: please add complete code, _tutsOfASection ... _section ... ecc

Comment: You are using empty list, dont need to make it nullable `List<Tutorial> _items = [];` also try to use `orElse` on `firstWhere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's actually the print that gives the error

```
debugPrint("items: ${_items?[i].pid}");
```

It will throw the exception when `_items` is empty. If you leave this out it might work, or rewrite it to something like

```
debugPrint("items: ${(_items ?? []).isEmpty ? 'null' : _items?[i].pid}");
```

EDIT:

actually this check has the same problem

```
if (_items?[i] == null) {
```

this will crash if _items is empty, so change it to this for example

```
if (_items == null || _items.isEmpty || _items?[i] == null) {
```